# Vehicle tracking

Tags: geolocation

All office buses would have Android 4G mobile phones with the driver, always switched on and always charging. These mobile phones need to broadcast realtime location possibly from an Android app, or perhaps from a web application running on Chrome. Office administrators and employees waiting for buses would then track the realtime location and recent path on a public URL using Chrome, without requiring to download any app. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible it is (some of the [Fleet maintenance](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_car_fleet#group_995) apps might even have such a feature). But asking for the corresponding software would be off-topic here; please see [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Google Plus location sharing.

1. No need for Android commuters to install any app. Request iPhone commuters to install and sign into Google Plus.
2. Provide each office bus with a 4G Android phone. Sign into Google Plus with a new Google Account for the bus, say TFL27@gmail.com.
3. Request commuters to be added to the circle of their bus.
4. Request office admins to be added to the circles of all buses.
5. [Enable Google Plus location sharing on the bus-tracking-phones:](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2998354?hl=en) Open the Google+ app Google+ icon. Touch the menu button or icon menu > Settings. Touch the account name, say TFL27@gmail.com. Touch Location sharing > next to "Location Sharing", turn the switch on. To share your precise location, scroll down to where it says "Pinpoint Location" and touch Edit. Choose the people and circles you'd like to share your precise location with > DONE at the top right.
6. Commuters and office admins should not share their location
7. Make continuous charging and anti-theft arrangements for these bus-tracking-phones.
8. Commuters will be able to see only their bus on Google Plus. Office admins will be able to see all buses on Google Plus.

### Sample Google Plus location sharing screen from CNET

[image]

**Reference:** [Four ways to share your exact location with family (and why)](http://www.cnet.com/news/location-tracking-apps/)

Comment: Reference http://www.cnet.com/news/location-tracking-apps/

Comment: @beeshyams, Stackexchange says that I need higher reputation to put more URLs in the answer.